# Javascript maximum call stack exceeded

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
'use stict';

function sumToRecursive(n) {
  if (n === 1) {
    return 1;
  }

  return n + sumToRecursive(n - 1);
}

function measureFunctionSpeed(f) {
  let start = Date.now();

  for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    f(i);
  }

  let end = Date.now();

  return end - start;
}

console.log(measureFunctionSpeed(sumToRecursive));
```

I'm getting a 'maximum call stack exceeded' error when I try to run the code above but I learned that the max call stack limit is around 10,000. My code goes 10 recursive levels deep at most but throws the same error. Does anyone know why?

[Screenshot of execution result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQDTn.jpg)

Comment: `0 !== 1` (and anything below `0`) hence the first `sumToRecursive()` call is an infinite "loop"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first iteration of the loop feeds the function `0` as `i`, which is not covered in the base case.

You can either start the `for` loop from `i= 1` or change the base case check to `if (n <= 1) {}` to cover the `0` case.

Comment: Yeah just realised when I looked back. I've been so confused for the past hour and just after I post the question on stack overflow I realise the problem. Thanks a lot anyways!